# combining two While & sql statments

Tags: php, mysql

I need to combine the two queries if possible or make them process one after the other. I'm assuming the `$Record_Count = $Record_Count + 1;` doesn't need to be there twice since that's just for the pagination script. (thanks in advance)

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * load_test WHERE language = '".$lang."' ORDER BY Id DESC, creationdate DESC LIMIT $start, 5");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $Record_Count = $Record_Count + 1;

$rec_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE com_id = '".$data[Id]."'");
while ($recdata = mysql_fetch_array($rec_res)) {
    $Record_Count = $Record_Count + 1;
```

Comment: need to be SELECT * from load_test instead SELECT * load_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF `$Record_Count` is just counting the number of returned rows you could always use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM load_test WHERE language = '".$lang."' ORDER BY Id DESC, creationdate DESC LIMIT $start, 5");
$rec_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE com_id = '".$data[Id]."'");

$Record_Count += mysql_num_rows($result) + mysql_num_rows($rec_res);
```

Comment: You could go faster still, and, if the purposes of these queries was simply to get the number of matching rows, use `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` and then sum the returned values.